# How to switch from controller to html code?

Tags: webstorm

I would like to know if there is a shortcut that allows me in WebStorm to switch from the controller page directly to the html page associated with it and vice versa.

WebStorm 2019.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using **Related Symbol…** popup for this. When you’re in one of the Angular component files, press `Ctrl+Cmd+Up` on MacOS or `Ctrl+Alt+Home` on Windows/Linux to see the list of related files. Then you can use the arrow keys to select the file you need and then press `Enter` to open it.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/01/webstorm-2019-1-early-access-preview/#easier_navigation_in_angular_projects